# How to write/store output of commands in a variable in Windows Command Line?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, command-line, command-line-interface

I want to set a directory path to variable using Windows Command Line without any user-interaction. So, like we do in Ubuntu OS:

```
my_path=$(pwd)
```

Here, output of **pwd** will get stored in **my_path**.

How to do this kind of task in Windows Command Line?

Comment: Just to clarify: In your example, `pwd` would not even be executed, and therefore no _output_ would be stored anywhere. What your code does is to store the content of the variable `pwd` into the variable `my_path`. If you happen to be on a platform, where shell variables are case-insensitive, your code would be equivalent to `my_path=$PWD`, and since bash automatically sets the variable `PWD` to the working directory (after each `cd`, `pushd` or `popd`), your code **does** have the desired effect, though because of different reason than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the more natural way in bash would have been

```
my_path=$PWD
```

Taking over this idea to Windows batch language, it would become

```
SET my_path=%CD%
```

The main difference is, that in Windows, `my_path` would end up in the environment automatically, while in bash, you would have to do this manually.